# can I have full alignment in a database text field?

Tags: mysql, formatting

I would like to ask if there is a way to format the text of a text-field in mysql database. I need this text at least full aligned. Thank you in advance.

Comment: where will you display the text in full alignment?

Comment: oh sorry, i load it in a php page

Answer (score -1):

if you would post it in an html web page, use jquery and get the element that has the text inside it.

example:

```
<div id="myid">echo your text here</div>
```

get the div id and apply replace using jquery

```
var longtext = $('#myid').text()
var alignedtext = "<div style='text-indent: 50px;'>"+longtext .replace( /\n/g, "</div><br><div style='text-indent: 50px;'>" )
$('#myid').html(alignedtext)
```

see the sample
http://jsfiddle.net/ss92qsx4/

Comment: Why jQuery? Why are you adding the text into the document this way instead of just emitting it with PHP? Why aren't you using a style sheet to do this? How does indenting 50px answer the question?

Comment: its an example in my past webpage where i displayed a certain text using jquery and adding an indentation , might as well suggest it as an example right? haven't you read the first phrase? "if you would post it in an html web page"